# Facebook: How to let Facebook Scraper recognize the hash in the URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, url

I have this link :

> http://example.com/mobile/#!/article/201073733551122/

When you access this link normally on a web browser, you'll be redirected to an article page, because i have written a JavaScript code in `mobile/index.php` that can do so which is:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var bitAfterHash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    bitAfterHash = bitAfterHash.split('!/').pop();
    var parts = bitAfterHash.split('/');
    var type = parts[0];
    var id = parts[1];
    if(type === 'article' || type === 'episode'){
        window.location.href="http://www.example.com/redirect/"+type+"/"+id;
    }
}
```

But when i post the exact same link on Facebook, Facebook will show the story of the page:

> http://www.example.com/mobile/

It's like Facebook ignored the `/#!/`

Is there anyway to let the Facebook see article page ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? Why don't you directly use the URL http://example.com/mobile/article/201073733551122/ without any hash part?

Comment: @ChristianEngel Because my mobile site is an AJAX site, it all uses the same URL, that's why i'm using the hash

Comment: Is only your mobile site built that way? Do you have a desktop site, containing the same content, with “normal” URLs? If so, just share the URL of that instead.

Comment: @CBroe Yes i have a desktop site, i'm talking about the mobile version, i have implemented a custom share buttons and they work perfectly, but when users press the safari's share button (for example), they will share the url not the content, so here lays the problem.

Comment: I know what you are talking about … but I am asking you why you are not sharing the desktop version of your articles instead? You can _specify_ which URL the Share button will share.

Comment: @CBroe I'm talking about the google chrome or safari's share button that i  located at the top right (in iOS) it's a button outside of our capability to program.

Comment: That's why i'm using the hash

Comment: Ah, ok, that wasn’t clear. AFAIK as I know Facebook supports the `_escaped_fragment_` syntax, that Google uses for crawling AJAX-based sites as well. So you will need to implement that on your server.

Comment: Can you provide a good example, and now that you understood the question can you remove the down-vote too :) ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know why, but facebook will keep stripping the information. What about turning the hash into a "?" and then accessing it like this:

```
if(window.location.href.search(/\?/) > -1) {
    var bitAfterHash = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
    bitAfterHash = bitAfterHash.split('!/').pop();
    var parts = bitAfterHash.split('/');
    var type = parts[0];
    var id = parts[1];
    if(type === 'article' || type === 'episode'){
        window.location.href="http://www.example.com/redirect/"+type+"/"+id;
    }
}
```

The URL would look like this:

> http://example.com/mobile/?!/article/201073733551122/

Comment: Can i change the string after the `?` in javascript ? because my site is AJAX

Comment: Sure, why won't you be able to change it? Its completely up to you.